# Infer that `a or `b, when one of them is not `None`, isn't `None`

Tags: python, mypy

Here's an example:

```
a: int | None
b: int | None
assert (a is not None) or (b is not None)
reveal_type(a or b)
```

If one of `a` and `b` is not `None`, then `a or b` must be not `None`.

But `mypy` reveals the type to be

```
main.py:4: note: Revealed type is "Union[builtins.int, None]"
```

Why is that? How can I get it to infer that `a or b` isn't `None`?

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=f5f8f94d89204920e9543ff52fcaf6ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens when `a == 0 and b is None`. The assert isn't triggered, but since `0` is falsy, the result of `0 or None` is `None`.

Comment: nice one, thanks. this is a good example of mypy helping to prevent a bug!